# PCIe NVMe SSD only found by BIOS after warm boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, uefi, nvme

I was recently given a Dell Latitude 5511 laptop with pre-installed Windows 10. I chose to replace Windows with Ubuntu 20.04 by letting Ubuntu install on the entire PCIe NVMe SSD (PC611 NVMe SK hynix 1TB). The only custom configuration chosen was LVM with encryption. The installation required Intel Rapid Storage Technology (RST) to be disabled and the SATA controller mode to be changed from RAID to AHCI. This made Windows miserable, and I therefore dropped my goal of multi-booting Windows and Ubuntu. I've also disabled fast boot such that it should spend more time on detecting devices.

During a cold boot I'm now facing the issue that the laptop only detects the disk, or at least detects that the disk has anything EFI-wise bootable, if I let it go into the one-time boot menu (F12) and then perform a warm boot using CTRL+ALT+DEL. During the warm boot it detects the disk, however, it complains about boot order:

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
Creating boot entry "boot0015" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"
```

I notice that each successful boot results in a new entry:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0014
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0015,000A,000B,0012,0013,0014
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* ubuntu
Boot0003* ubuntu
Boot0004* ubuntu
Boot0005* ubuntu
Boot0006* ubuntu
Boot0007* ubuntu
Boot0008* ubuntu
Boot0009* ubuntu
Boot000A* Onboard NIC(IPV4)
Boot000B* Onboard NIC(IPV6)
Boot000C* ubuntu
Boot000D* ubuntu
Boot000E* ubuntu
Boot000F* ubuntu
Boot0010* ubuntu
Boot0011* ubuntu
Boot0012* USB NIC(IPV4)
Boot0013* USB NIC(IPV6)
Boot0014* UEFI: PC611 NVMe SK hynix 1TB, Partition 1
Boot0015* ubuntu
```

It isn't sufficient to perform a warm boot without having been in the one-time boot menu.

The disk isn't listed when I'm in the one-time boot menu after the initial cold boot. If I go into the menu after the warm boot the disk is listed.

I hope this is related to Unix and Linux rather than being a BIOS-only issue.

How do I make the laptop detect the disk during a cold boot?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a BIOS/UEFI issue, or possibly some kind of hardware fault with either the Dell machine or the NVME ssd. The failure to detect the nvme on a cold boot happens long before ubuntu or even grub has any chance to be involved.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware. You may want to houseclean UEFI entries. You have many duplicate Ubuntu entries. At some point it may fill up & fail. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228 See also `man efibootmgr` Mostly discussion of 5000 series,but many links.  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2454083

Comment: I've now tried many, many things, sadly without luck so far. I'm also becoming convinced that it's a BIOS/UEFI issue and not related to Ubuntu. I believe all firmwares were upgraded by Dell's update software in Windows when I used the laptop with Windows a few times right after unboxing. I'll get back to this question if I ever find a solution. As mentioned, my workaround is to boot into the one-time boot menu and then reboot, after which the disk will be found. An entry is still being added to EFI on each boot, i.e. I'll have to clean the list once in a while.

Comment: I does sound very much like a BIOS/UEFI or SSD firmware issue, not an Ubuntu issue. Can you install another hard disk to try to boot from (or a USB device or digital disc [CD/DVD]) and see if you can probe the BIOS from there to see what it's reporting?